# Memory leak causing app to crash

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management, crash

My app gives a low memory crash on the device and not on the simulator.I used Instruments and i think that the problem lies in the following part

```
       UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

       [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gembtnblu.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];<br>

        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, TOOLBAR_BUTTON_WIDTH , TOOLBAR_BUTTON_HEIGHT);<br>

        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",choice] forState:UIControlStateNormal];<br>

        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ChoiceButtonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [button setTag:choice];

        UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

        //Add button to the array
        [tempItems addObject:customBarItem];

        if (isReviewing == TRUE) {
            customBarItem.customView.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;
        }
        //release buttons
        [customBarItem release];

        numberOfChoices++;
```

But im not able to spot the problem.Please help guuys, i have beeen stuck at this for days now

heres some more code

`NSArray *items=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray *)tempItems];

         [tempItems release];`

```
//add array of buttons to toolbar
[toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

the static analyser says that theres a potential leak with 'items' array.But if i put in a release statement, the app crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you release the toolbar after adding it as a subview? If you did not, and are not releasing the toolbar in the dealloc, there's your leak.

Answer (score 0):

Is the image you're creating large? It could be that you're loading a huge message into memory and not releasing it.

I'd recommend running the static analyzer on this code (Build and Analyze), the errors should help you understand where you aren't releasing things that you should be.

Comment: the image is a small png.I used the static analyzer, which told me that im leaking an array.But when i released it, the app crashes right in the simulator.Im stuk because im debugging over teamviewer and cant debug on the actual device.ill post more code

Comment: If it crashes when you release the array, then you're likely releasing it before your program is finished using it. Try placing the release later in your code, or perhaps attaching the array to an autorelease pool.

Comment: auto release makes it crash after a few goes, while release crashes it immediately :-(

Answer (score 0):

The snippet of source code you posted does not contain memory management errors. I am assuming here that the image you load is small, since this is for a button. Note that imageNamed: caches the image but assuming the image is small this is not a problem.

Either the problem lies somewhere else in the code, or on your device you have too much applications open simultaneously. Beware of applications running in background: these still are eating memory. Try closing all of the applications and running again yours on the device. See if you experience exactly the same behavior when executing the same code snippet.

Comment: yes the person at the other side closed all the other applictions and tried.This is actually a quiz app and the buttons are used to enter choices,Each time a next button is clicked, the buttons are reloaded.At that point , instruments registers a leak..It happens everytime.

Comment: Wait a minute. The leak may not necessarily associated to your code: it may be a block of memory allocated in one of the framework you are linking, something that will be released later. Did you check if the leak actually refers to your source code? Instruments clearly marks each leaked block as belonging to your code (and it even tell you where the leak originates) or to library/framework code.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be releasing old buttons and lists before allocating new ones.  Perhaps you should reuse the old buttons instead of creating new similar ones.

Comment: Hmmm.But dont know where to do that, as im releasing all created buttons after adding them to the tool bar

Comment: Are you releasing the old toolbar and the buttons inside it?

Comment: was just looking at it.The buttons are all released,the tool bar is a property.So cant release it in between, or have i got the memory management concepts all wrong??